# delete folder/files and subfolder

Tags: c#

I want to delete a folder containing files and a subfolder, also containing files. I have used everything, but it is not working for me. I'm using the following function in my web-application asp.net:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder_path);
dir.Delete(true);
```

Sometimes it deletes a folder, or sometimes it doesn't. If a subfolder contains a file, it only deletes the file, and not the folder as well.

Comment: If tou use Seven/Vista sometimes you cant delete folder if Explorer is open on that folder(or deeper)

Comment: @ Stecya: I am using this as a web application.

Comment: Is an error message produced/logged, or does the delete simply fail silently?

Comment: You might have limited permissions on the files/folders you can delete from a web-app.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? If so, please update the question with details about that.

Comment: If the directory is not empty you have to delete the files first and then you can delete the directory.

Comment: @bojanskr: the directory isnt empty, i want to delete all the file and sub folder regardless of it is empty or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks about right: http://www.ceveni.com/2008/03/delete-files-in-folder-and-subfolders.html

```
//to call the below method
EmptyFolder(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\your Path"))


using System.IO; // dont forget to use this header

//Method to delete all files in the folder and subfolders

private void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {       
       file.Delete();
     }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
      EmptyFolder(subfolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not Directory.Delete(folder_path, recursive:true); ?

Answer (score 41):

[`Directory.Delete(folder_path, recursive: true);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

would also get you the desired result and a lot easier to catch errors.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way in my experience is this

```
Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
```

But I am experiencing a problem with this function in a scenario when I am trying to create the same folder right after its deletion.

```
Directory.Delete(outDrawableFolder, true);
//Safety check, if folder did not exist create one
if (!Directory.Exists(outDrawableFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outDrawableFolder);
}
```

Now when my code tries to create some file in the outDrwableFolder it ends up in exception. like for instance creating image file using api Image.Save(filename, format).

Somehow this piece of helper function works for me.

```
public static bool EraseDirectory(string folderPath, bool recursive)
{
    //Safety check for directory existence.
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        return false;

    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    //Iterate to sub directory only if required.
    if (recursive)
    {
        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
        {
            EraseDirectory(dir, recursive);
        }
    }
    //Delete the parent directory before leaving
    Directory.Delete(folderPath);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the same by using the `DirectoryInfo` instance method. I just faced this problem and I believe this can resolve your problem too.

```
var fullfilepath = Server.MapPath(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderPath"]);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo deleteTheseFiles = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(fullfilepath);

deleteTheseFiles.Delete(true);
```

[For more details have a look at this link as it looks like the same.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I use the Visual Basic version because it allows you to use the standard dialogs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24t911bf(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Directory.Delete(path,recursive:true);

this code works for delete folder with N subfolder and files in it.