# Automatically deleting Enterprise Library 5 Rolling Log files

Tags: file, logging, file-io, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I have Enterprise Library Logging used throughout my project which is working perfectly, however I have noticed that the folder containing the logs has started to become bloated with old logs that are no longer needed. My set up in app.config is:

```
    <add name="CommonListener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="D:\Logs\Common.log" footer="   "
    formatter="Text Formatter" header="   " rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
    rollInterval="Midnight" rollSizeKB="1000000"/>
```

At present I am able to delete these manually, but that will lead to problems down the line as I won't have access to where they will be stored. Is there a configuration that I can add into the config file that will flag them to be deleted after 'x' amount of days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by limiting the amount of files that Enterprise Logging sotes by adding the following to app.config within the listener declaration:

```
maxArchivedFiles="20"
```

Now the logging will only keep up to 20 files and delete the oldest as this threshold is reached.

Another way I found to do this which does not involve Enterprise Library can be found here:
[Background Worker Check For When It's Midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053695/background-worker-check-for-when-its-midnight)

This done through System.IO to raise an event when a certain time has elapsed. It is then combined with a function to delete all files as found in this answer:

[delete folder/files and subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092611/delete-folder-files-and-subfolder)